# delete duplicates with two ifs

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-delete

We have a Microsoft SQL Server table `[database].[dbo].[UserInAppPurchase]` with this columns:

```
   [Id]
  ,[UserEmail]
  ,[UserId]
  ,[PurchaseDate]
  ,[ProductId]
  ,[TransactionId]
  ,[OriginalTransactionId]
  ,[ValidationTime]
  ,[ValidationReceipt]
  ,[ValidFrom]
  ,[ValidTo]
  ,[Platfrom]
```

So a `UserID` can have multiple records of the same purchase by error. The duplicates would have an identical `ValidTo` date.

So how would I delete all duplicates? In the end each `UserId` would have exactly one entry with that particular `ValidTo` date.

Thanks for the help

Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row_number()` with an updatable CTE comes to mind:

```
with todelete as (
      select uiap.*, row_number() over (partition by userid, validto order by id) as seqnum
      from UserInAppPurchase uiap 
     )
delete from todelete
    where seqnum > 1;
```